# How to Wire a 100amp Sub panel 300feet away from main panel

Tags: electrical

i am currently trying to figure out the best way to feed a 100amp panel fed from a 200amp Main that is 300 feet away from each other. Do you have any suggestions? and yes i know its going to be expensive.

Comment: A 100 Amp panel could have a huge load - as much as 80 Amp continuous, or a tiny load - as little as 20A (with occasional higher amounts). Some key questions: What is your *actual* anticipated load? Is the 300 feet inside, outside or some of each? If outside, how hard to dig a trench for conduit?

Comment: This is pretty much the same as these, barring a small detail or two: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/74445/18078  https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/203665/18078

Comment: What loads are on this new panel, and can we presume that this is an outdoor/buried run?

Comment: Also similar, varying a different detail https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/195308/18078

Comment: Won't be so bad, $750 for the good stuff (#2/0).  If that's too much, for half the money you could 90A (#2) but the voltage drop would be pretty bad.  Depending on what your loads actually are.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum legal size for 100A is #1 aluminum, however, voltage drop will be almost 5% with that wire.

2/0 aluminum is at a pricing and availability sweet-spot and is probably just right for that distance.

Voltage drop is proportional to *actual load* so it matters what the loads actually are.

You're supposed to breaker the circuit for 125% of the expected load, so a 100A breaker implies you expect <=80A of load.  *At "full" 80A load your voltage drop will be 3.25% @ 300' w/ 2/0 aluminum wire, which is perfectly fine*.  $2.50/foot so $750 whole job.

The minimum aluminum size you must use is #1, and #2 is legal if you downsize to 90A breaker... but there's not much cost savings to downsize wire.  Even #2 is $1.68/foot.

Aluminum wire is the preferred wire for heavy feeders of this sort.  Disregard anything you may have heard about aluminum wire *for small 15/20A branch circuits*; that is not applicable here.

If you really are hell-bent on superstition, you can pay $14/foot ($4200 whole job) for #1 copper, which will give you 2.99% voltage drop at 80A.